# How to get access token from Single Sign On portal for multiple sites

Tags: asp.net, cookies, oauth, single-sign-on, owin

We are building several websites/products, if a user has an account on one site they will also be allowed access to all other sites.

Let's say we have the following setup:

**Clients**

- site1.com
- site2.com

**Single Sign On Portal**

- sso.company.com

**APIs**

- api1.company.com
- api2.company.com

The Single Sign On Portal supports multiple OAuth providers, such as Google, Microsoft, Facebook, etc and this is all working great built on top of the default ASP.NET Web Forms template in VS 2015 using OWIN and Idenity.
The SSO site is logging the user in an using a cookie for authentication, which works fine while still on the SSO site. Now we need to return a token that the client site can use to know that the user is authenticated

Now the challange here is how do we exchange the cookie to a token that we can return to the client(s) to use in the Authorization header in request sent to our APIs?

Should we generate a token our selves or is there some built in functionality we can use for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen most people generate a token themselves and then multiple accounts can be linked to that same user in your account (i.e. a user could log into both FB and Google). Most of the SSO providers have a way to get an identity token or one time use code for your server to use and get user info like FacebookId. The key is ensuring that identity token came from FB and not a third party.

Auth0 is a pretty good service if you want a managed route. Even if you don't use them, they have a lot of good resources on oauth. (I have no affiliation with them other than that we used them before.) we also have a little more info on auth: https://www.moesif.com/blog/technical/restful-apis/Authorization-on-RESTful-APIs/